# Stripe accessing the metadata within a PHP script

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve a line of metadata (order_no) within Stripe's checkout.session.completed event but I don't know how to go about it. I'm using PHP. I don't know how to query the event to retrieve the checkout.session object from within a PHP script, so I can read the metadata. Could someone please show by example how to achieve that without installing addons such as Slim, etc. I have looked at multiple examples on this site but have not been able to understand them. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$order = $mysqli->escape_string(md5(rand(0,20)));
$amt = '299';

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create(

[
'payment_intent_data'=>['description' =>'my purchases'],        
'metadata' => [
    'order_id' => $order
],
'line_items' => [
    [
        'name' => 'My Products',
        'description' => 'My online products',
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'amount' => $amt,
        'quantity' => 1 
  ]],
    'success_url' => $MySite.'success.php',
    'cancel_url' => $MySite.'cancel.html'
]);

header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Questions requesting how-to material or requesting code without self effort are considered off-topic on SO. Please provide us with a specific programming problem, the attempt you tried to solve the issue and debugging information for context.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry. Here's what I've got - which was taken from the Stripe site and modified to suit. It works fine (the transaction takes place). And when I look at the session object on Stripe's event page I can see the order no. What I'm trying to do is retrieve that order number via PHP so I don't have to view it through the Stripe Dashboard. Here's the code I'm trying to follow on from.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that I could edit the original post until too late. But remedied now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what specifically you're asking for. Are you just wanting to access `order_id` within `metadata`? In which case, you could save the entire array to a separate variable, and then access it directly (and pass that variable into the Stripe object). `$data = ['metadata' => ['order_id' => $order_id], ...]; Session::create($data);` Does https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-metadata or https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=php help?

Comment: Hi WoundedStevenJones - thanks for your suggestions. I tried retrieving the session (as in your second link) but kept getting an invalid session. It says no parameters are required but the example given is $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
  'cs_test_a12aOaYlyA3LOAEwE1ZUh0wJMUTK2W4Vm4I4IB63KyaPYXQ2JuJTXrNalL',
  []); So I'm quite confused myself by the example given in the link.

Comment: I finally understand what I need to do!! Thank you to those who posted. You may not have directly resolved the problem for me but your contributions helped me to see what I was doing wrong!! I have just this minute retrieved a session and all the data contained within it!